# What is the best way to model such time series?

Tags: time-series, arima, lstm, univariate

I have this time series where a peak occurs every around 5 years and the structure changes after each peak. What do you think is the best way to model such time series? Can this be modeled using the variable itself?

[image: GDP Univariate Time Series]

```
GDP         EoQ
2002-09-01  93.4
2002-12-01  87.4
2002-03-01  87.2
2002-06-01  86.5
2003-09-01  96.4
2003-12-01  90.2
2003-03-01  89.6
2003-06-01  89.3
2004-09-01  100.5
2004-12-01  94.1
2004-03-01  93.3
2004-06-01  93.1
2005-09-01  104.9
2005-12-01  98.3
2005-03-01  97.6
2005-06-01  97.7
2006-09-01  111.4
2006-12-01  105.2
2006-03-01  104.3
2006-06-01  105.2
2007-09-01  178.0
2007-12-01  175.0
2007-03-01  175.1
2007-06-01  182.3
2008-09-01  189.8
2008-12-01  188.5
2008-03-01  187.9
2008-06-01  195.2
2009-09-01  200.6
2009-12-01  196.2
2009-03-01  195.9
2009-06-01  204.1
2010-09-01  209.9
2010-12-01  205.9
2010-03-01  206.8
2010-06-01  215.1
2011-09-01  221.4
2011-12-01  217.7
2011-03-01  199.0
2011-06-01  215.8
2012-09-01  437.7
2012-12-01  432.2
2012-03-01  412.4
2012-06-01  430.8
2013-09-01  450.6
2013-12-01  441.9
2013-03-01  420.7
2013-06-01  438.1
2014-09-01  458.0
2014-12-01  448.8
2014-03-01  435.2
2014-06-01  460.4
2015-09-01  478.9
2015-12-01  467.4
2015-03-01  444.8
2015-06-01  472.1
2016-09-01  494.1
2016-12-01  477.1
2016-03-01  452.1
2016-06-01  482.8
2017-09-01  810.7
2017-12-01  843.7
2017-03-01  863.4
2017-06-01  897.4
2018-09-01  853.0
2018-12-01  888.5
2018-03-01  910.3
2018-06-01  945.1
2019-09-01  895.9
2019-12-01  933.2
2019-03-01  958.6
```

Comment: If you are happy with my answers , please accept them to close the question

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very similar to the problem of predicting daily ridership in the Paris metro which is open 18 hours of each day . It had two powerful seasonal factors DAILY and HOURLY. Your 71 quarterly values has a quarterly and 5 year seasonality thus it requires multiple deterministic seasonality components.

I introduced you data to AUTOBOX , a piece of software that I had to re-configure (expand it's functionality) based upon multiple seasonal-deterministic factors and a possible arima component and latent anomalies.

Here is your data [image] , Here is the Actual/Fit and Forecast for the next 20 quarters (5 years) [image]

The hybrid model is here using when needed quarterly seasonal dummies AND seasonal dummies reflecting the 20 period cycle. [image] and here in more detail [image] and here [image]. It includes an arima component (1,0,0) and a pulse indicator at period 61 suggesting a change in trend within the 5 year cycle . N.B. this not-so-subtle characteristic is visually obvious and found automatically using Intervention Detection procedures detailed here http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html and every place good time series statistical process are adhered to.

The forecast plot with 95% forecast intervals is here using monte-carlo procedures is here [image]

Here is the 1,000 value simulation for the first period out .[image] .

All models are wrong but the model presented here is less wrong then a lot of other models and can be improved by incorporating weighted least squares to deal with a deterministic change ( before and after period 41 ) in the variance of the errors. Look closely at the plot of the original series.